# Permit use hardware (camera,microphone,etc) to application for some time, not forever

Tags: permissions

In Android 6 and latter, when application asks for permission (for example camera access) user can

- allow,
- or dismiss,
- or check 'do not ask any more' and dismiss.

I would like to have one more option:

- **allow for some time** (5sec,1min,5min,3days)

Comment: I am sorry but this is not the way Android works. There may be way on rooted devices or using a privacy aware custom ROM for your device, but those are not of--the-shelve solutions and may require a lot of work.

Comment: You can run a cron daemon as root which periodically checks for specified permissions on specified apps. And if the permission is granted, it will revoke that. It needs some scripting. May also work on `adb shell` but non-root daemons may get killed. Possibly some automation app can do that for you.